# executing command prompt command in MySql trigger

Tags: mysql, trigger

I have one table called table1. In it there are two fields, let say field1 and field2. What I am trying to do is that, when there are records inserted into table1, the values of field1 and field2 get stored in one text file called abc.txt which is on c drive.

I want to do it by calling the command prompt command which is called inside table1's After insert trigger called trigger1.

I have done it in SQL Server but I need it using MySQL. Here is the SQL Server trigger:

```
create trigger [dbo].[trigger1] on [dbo].[table1] 
for insert

As 

Declare @field_1 varchar(50),@field_2 int,@cmd varchar(250);

select @field_1=i.field1 from inserted i;
select @field_2=i.field2 from inserted i;

PRINT @field_1
Print @field_2;

SET @cmd= 'echo ' + @field_1+','+cast(@field_2 as varchar)+ '>C:\abc.txt'
EXEC Master..xp_cmdshell @cmd
```

The MySQL trigger that I have written is:

```
delimiter #
create trigger trigger1 after insert on table1 
for each row
begin
Declare field_1 varchar(50);
Declare field_2 int(50);
Declare cmd varchar(200);

SET field_1 = NEW.field1;
SET field_2  = NEW.field2;

System echo field_1 > C:\abc.txt
end#
delimiter ;
```

After executing this command it gives an error as

```
ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'echo
field1 > C:\abc.txt
end' at line 11
```

I am new to MySQL. Maybe I am doing it wrong. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

`system` is one of MySQL's internal commands, interpreted by the *mysql* command-line tool rather than by the SQL engine, as stated in the [manual](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-commands.html):

> [**mysql**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) sends each SQL statement that you issue to the server to be executed. There is also a set of commands that [**mysql**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql.html) itself interprets. [...]
>
> ```
> system    (\!) Execute a system shell command.
> ```
>
> [...]

You can't run the `system` command inside a stored program (and that includes a trigger), because the entire body of the stored program is sent to the server and the server won't recognise `system`.

However, you can get an output file with [**SELECT ... INTO OUTFILE FILE**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/select-into.html):

```
  SELECT field_1 INTO OUTFILE '/tmp/abc.txt'
  FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
  LINES TERMINATED BY '\n';
```